# Creating multiple tables with a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook in which each worksheet has identically formatted data but for different entities. I'd like to make each of these in to a table, but I'm unfamiliar with how to write anything like this. There's too many sheets to make doing this by hand an efficient option. Below is my attempt at coding this but it's pretty broken. Again, I've never actually tried to do anything like this.

My intention is that I would have this workbook open, I'd run the macro, and it would loop through each sheet and create a table for the present data. Then I would play around with the pivot table I'd use these table for. Can anyone offer some help, please?

```
Sub Create_Tables()

    Dim wrksht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ActiveSheet
           .ListObjects.Add(xlSrnRange, Range("AE1", Range ("AE1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)) , , xlYes)
           .Name:= .Name & "_Table"

           .ListObjects(.Name & "_Table").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"

    Next sht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tested code will work. Hopefully you can discern the slight modifications I have made.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Tables()

    Dim wrksht As Worksheet

    For Each wrksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With wrksht

            Dim myTable As ListObject

            Set myTable = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, wrksht.Range("AE1", wrksht.Range("AE1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)), , xlYes)

            With myTable
                .Name = .Name & "_Table"
                .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
            End With

        End With

    Next wrksht

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked amazingly. I will refer back to this and make sure I understand looping. If I may, is there a way to name the table after a single cell in the worksheet?

Comment: @jules325  - `.Name = wrksht.Range("A1").Value`, for example

Comment: Scott, you have 1) Made my day much easier, and 2) increased my knowledge of coding. Thanks very very much! Best,